# WPF C# DataGrid binding to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm new to WPF C# development... pretty good at SSIS/SSRS but this one is throwing me. Ultimately I am trying to display a table of data from a stored procedure in a DataGrid. I can get this to work for a single table, but the stored procedure joins many tables and has a date parameter I need to pass in. I appreciate any direction you can give me - there seems to be almost nothing out there instructing how to do this easily.

First, here's how I am getting my connection string. I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project with "Add new Item":

[image]

I'm checking all stored procedures and tables, and I name it `PlacementInvoicesEntities`.

Here's the `app.config` contents:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PlacementInvoicesEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/PlacementData.csdl|res://*/PlacementData.ssdl|res://*/PlacementData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYSERVER;initial catalog=PlacementInvoices;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My XAML that works just fine for a single table is as follows:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
              Name="PermInvoices" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              FrozenColumnCount="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Invoice #" Binding="{Binding Path=InvoiceNum}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Placement #" Binding="{Binding Path=PlacementNum}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Loaded" Binding="{Binding Path=dateLoaded}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Approval Sent" Binding="{Binding Path=ApprovalEmailSent}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Approver Email" Binding="{Binding Path=ApproverEmail}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Billing Email" Binding="{Binding Path=billingEmail}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In the code behind the page I have this - it works for just that table `PermAutomation_Log` but I'd like to work work for a stored procedure, let's call it `spPermLog` with the date parameter `@ApprovalDate`:

```
private void DispData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PlacementInvoicesEntities conn = new PlacementInvoicesEntities();

        List<PermAutomation_Log> TableData = conn.PermAutomation_Log.ToList();
        PermInvoices.ItemsSource = TableData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have a datePicker on the page named "DateLoaded" that I would want to feed into the Stored Procedure parameter.  I've tried everything I can think of, and I can't even get a stored procedure with no parameters to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I should add - if you are wondering why I wouldn't just do this in SSRS since right now it's effectively just a report - it's because I need the interface to be interact.  I need the end user to be able to update specific values back to the SQL table.  So after I get this loaded, my next challenge is making it possible to update records from this interface.

Comment: Why not make the query a view and use that as a normal read-only table? Or even write LINQ in .NET for the joins instead of putting it in a SP

Comment: if not, check out https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/call-store-procedure-from-entity-framework/

Comment: How is the SP defined? What does it return/select?

Comment: @fredrik - I probably could make the query a view, I would just need to still specify a WHERE clause.  But dude - I think that c-sharpcorner link is it.  I'll try it out now.

Comment: @mm8 The SP returns a table of data.

Comment: I spoke too soon, the c-sharpcorner wasn't quite it.  I can't figure how that would work in a WPF project.

I've seen a lot of reference to using SQLCommand to call stored procedures with parameters... but the examples never do a good job of setting up the connection string in app.data.  If someone can help me figure out the right way to add a connection string and use SQLCommand that would help.  but every thing I try this, I can't get "Open" on conn.Open() to be recognized.  :(

Comment: Your question posted `PlacementInvoicesEntities` your class that actually queries the data.  If you can EDIT your existing post and put that code in, you'll get farther.   Also, if you comment me back with your email, I would be willing to help you out as a newbie in C#/wpf.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it to work after continuing to research ways to bind SQL with WPF DataGrid.  This is how it worked for me.  Maybe it'll help some other newbie like myself.

First, I was apparently overthinking the connection string.  All I needed was a simple connection string in app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PlacementInvoices" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=PlacementInvoices;integrated security=True"/>
```

And then I was able to use SQLCommand to build a query string, and bind it to my table.  This works even with my DatePicker.

```
private void DispData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime? SelectedDate = DateLoaded.SelectedDate;
        
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PlacementInvoices"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;

        CmdString = "exec ssrs_DHAutomationLog '" + SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "'";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Invoices");
                sda.Fill(dt);
                PermInvoices.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[This is the article that helped me out](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/data-binding-in-wpf-datagrid-control-using-sql-server-databa/)

Comment: aahhhgggg... Don't concatenate command strings.  Learn how to parameterize your queries... Look into SqlCommandParameter().  Different databases use different character to denote parameter.  @ for sqlserver, : for sqlite, ? for others as unnamed parameter place holder, and parameters need to be added in same sequence for each ? used, etc.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp I guess old habits die hard.  I'll look into SqlCommandParameter().  Thanks for the hint.